# "Can't assign to function call" using "with"

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement

I am trying to write a script that will read all the files in a directory and dump them into a single file. What I have is:

```
from glob import glob

directory = glob('/Users/jmanley/Desktop/Table/*')

with outfile as open('/Users/jmanley/Desktop/Table.sql', 'wb'):
    for file in directory:
        with readfile as open(file, 'rb'):
                        outfile.write(readfile.read())
```

I get `"can't assign to function call"` as the error message, and IDLE marks the `with` keyword as the location of the error.

If I rewrite the script to use `open()` and `close()` methods rather than using the `with` keyword, it runs without issue:

```
from glob import glob

directory = glob('/Users/jmanley/Desktop/Table/*')
outfile = open('/Users/jmanley/Desktop/Table.sql', 'wb')

for file in directory:
    readfile = open(file, 'rb')
    outfile.write(readfile.read())
    readfile.close()

outfile.close()
```

Why am I getting the `"can't assign to function call"` error? The only time I've seen this happen is if an assignment is reversed: `a + b = variable`. Am I just missing something incredibly obvious?

Comment: That should be `with open('/Users/jmanley/Desktop/Table.sql', 'wb') as outfile:`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that:

```
with foo as bar:
```

is (very, very roughly) equivalent to:

```
bar = foo
```

*(This is consistent with other uses of `as` in Python, e.g. `except ValueError as err:`.)*

Therefore when you try:

```
with outfile as open('/Users/jmanley/Desktop/Table.sql', 'wb'):
```

you are actually trying to assign:

```
open('/Users/jmanley/Desktop/Table.sql', 'wb') = outfile
```

which is *clearly* incorrect. Instead, you need to reverse the statement:

```
with open('/Users/jmanley/Desktop/Table.sql', 'wb') as outfile:
```

See also [the relevant PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/).